# Catch lines in "interact" block

Tags: expect

I want to catch all lines in the interact block:

```
spawn proc

interact {
    -o -re
    "a" { do something }
    "b" { do something }
    catch all { send_user theLineFromTheSpawnedProcess + " ok" }
}
```

I try with re ".*" but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally ended up using pexpect.